# Accessing main Queue in Cocoa Touch Static Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, static-libraries, grand-central-dispatch

I have made simple cocoa touch static library(By following Simple Tutorial from http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial )

Everything is working fine in that library. Now i need access to mainQueue of the application in which this library is used. I am using following command to access it

```
dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
```

but it gives `BAD_ACCESS` error to me. Now i tried to create my own queue and pass it as argument to other method in my library, it creates the queue but it is giving me again `BAD_ACCESS` when i pass this to my method as argument. Even it is giving me same error, when i assign it to other variable.

creating queue as:

```
dispatch_queue_t abcQueue = dispatch_queue_create("abcQueue", NULL);
```

now assigning it to other variables or passing it to my method gives me `BAD_ACCESS` error.
Please help me if anyone getting same error and have solved such issue.

Comment: Some more context wouldn't hurt, also I am pretty sure it is BAD_ACCESS not EXCESS..

Comment: sorry,Spelling mistake, edited now

Comment: Now the only issue remaining is the context for the question. There is only ever one main queue, does not matter whether you are inside a static library or not, the bad access is likely caused by how you handle the passed in queue argument, see, EXC_BAD_ACCESS is related to how you access memory, to be more precise, it signifies you have messed up when accessing it - more here http://loufranco.com/blog/understanding-exc_bad_access

Comment: You can try by putting this code in library, it is not even allowing me to assign one queue variable to other

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I'm not sure how different it is, but give it a try and let us know.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //do stuff
    });
```

Comment: Same for you as i replied in another answer's comment: This code is running good in application, but when i am putting it in Library, this is also giving same error

Answer (score 0):

You have number of options to run your code in main Thread

1) You can also try with NSOperationQueue:-

```
// Get hold of main queue (main thread)
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: ^ {
        //Do something
    }];
```

2) You can also do a trial with performSelector

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: This code is running in application, but when i am putting it in Library, this is also giving same error